# IE8 Jquery show() div increases size of parent div

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a Jquery popup like this

```
$("[id=messagelink]").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).next('#popupmessage').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).next('#popupmessage').hide();
});
```

The div code:

```
<div>......
<a href='' id='messagelink' name='messagelink' touserid='1' ><img src='images/icons/mail.png' width='15' height='15' /></a>
<div id='popupmessage' class='popup'>Blaaah</div>";
......
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.popup {
display: none;
padding: 10px;
background: #eeeeee;
color: #000000;
border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
font-size: 90%;
position: absolute;
}
```

All works fine in FF, Chrome, Opera but in IE the popup is shown but it is increasing the height and width of the parent DIV.
And what's worse, it is adding horizontal and vertical scrollbar to the DIV by overflowing it. YUK !

I removed the padding from the CSS and then the problem is fixed. But I need a nice popup message instead of a cropped one.

What can be done ?

Thanks for your help.
Coenos

Answer (score 0):

If you are not targeting IE 7 or less, you can use div{box-sizing: border-box;}. whatever padding you give will be padded "INSIDE" the specified height & width of DIV and not outside.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the div position relative. I have never experienced this myself.

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HaJjH/2/

I checked in a simulator of IE8, you can check on real IE8 and see if it works